# Multiple aggregation and variable calculation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

i have such data

```
mydata=structure(list(id = c(15010124001, 15010153006, 15010169005, 
15010228019, 15010229028, 6010001012, 6010012023, 6010014015, 
6010015008, 6020001014, 6020002037), sqr = c("14", "9", "2", 
"21", "13", "26", "17,2", "21,7", "4,7", "32,2", "36,1"), por = c("alpin", 
"alpin", "alpin", "alpin", "alpin", "Yornik birch", "Yornik birch", 
"Yornik birch", "Yornik birch", "Yornik birch", "Yornik birch"
), zap = c("2100", "1100", "1700", "1000", "1300", "200", "197,6744186", 
"170,5069124", "212,7659574", "301,242236", "398,8919668"), zappor = c("1260", 
"330", "850", "1000", "910", "200", "197,6744186", "170,5069124", 
"212,7659574", "301,242236", "398,8919668"), zapvyd = c(2940L, 
990L, 340L, 2100L, 1690L, 520L, 340L, 370L, 100L, 970L, 1440L
), coef = c(6L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L
), age = c(130L, 100L, 130L, 150L, 120L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 15L, 
20L, 20L), vys = c(21L, 17L, 19L, 17L, 18L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), diam = c(26L, 18L, 24L, 28L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), polnot = c("0,6", "0,4", "0,6", "0,4", "0,5", "0,7", "0,8", 
"0,7", "0,7", "0,5", "0,6"), BON = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L), clust = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

i need for each cluster of each `por`(categorical variable) aggregate `sqr` by sum.
of course i can do so

```
ag <- aggregate(sqr~clust+por , data = mydat, sum)
```

but not so simple,because
then i need calculate the percentage of `sqr` by por for each cluster.
example, when i manually perform

```
por clust   sum
alpin   1   25(14+9+2)
alpin   2   34(21+13
Yornik birch    1   43,2
Yornik birch    2   94,7
```

But then I need a more complex aggregation, and I do not understand how to do it. Thus, I need to calculate what percentage of the total `sqr` of a particular category of `por` variable, each cluster occupies.
for example for the first cluster of `por=alpin`. `sqr`= 25, and the total number of observations in the cluster1 is 3(obs.)

```
3/25 = 0.12 (12%)
```

as output table

```
por   clust sum       percent
alpin   1   25(14+9+2)  12
```

after that i need calculate new variable. Calculate `sqr` for all `por` categories and all `clusters`

```
    14
    9
    2
    21
    13
    26
    17,2
    21,7
    4,7
    32,2
    36,1
sum 169,9
```

then divide by this sum, the number of observations in each cluster of each `por`. for example for the first cluster
alpin categories= 3(obs.in the first clust) / 169.9 = 0.017657446 (1.7%)
and the final table will look like this (for example, the first cluster of alpine `por`)
indeed this desired output

```
por clust sum percent percent1
alpin 1     25  12      1.7
```

How do I make such transformations ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easier if you breakdown the problem into steps and code each step with dplyr.

1. need to create numeric values
2. need to perform a computation by group
3. compute by group
4. in order to compute the entire sum, we need to ungroup
5. compute second percentage

```r
mydata %>%
  mutate(sqr = as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", sqr))) %>% # --> convert to numeric as it is string
  group_by(por, clust) %>% # --> group by what you want
  mutate(
    pct = length(sqr) / sum(sqr), # --> create first percentage
    pct2 = length(id) # --> create second percentage, incomplete for now
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>% # --> no need to have anything grouped now
  mutate(pct2 = pct2 / sum(sqr)) # --> update second percentage with actual calc
```